# Python exe fails when in unicode folder. Error - Pythondll

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I created a hello.py.
Then created setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe

setup(console=["hello.py"])
```

Then using `python setup.py py2exe` created build.
This is successful and works fine.

Now I saved this build in a Folder with unicode name (ex - औgfgf)
When I execute this build it gives error

```
C:\?gfgf\dist>hello.exe
LoadLibrary(pythondll) failedThe specified module could not be found.
C:\?gfgf\dist\PYTHON27.DLL
C:\?gfgf\dist>
```